# Disable Delphi XE automatic update check

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

i have  two delphi xe  installled in different virtual machines (Running in Windows 7 64 Bits), one of these versions of delphi xe is  15.0.3890.34076 . Now  to give support to my customers over  a  particular version of my product which was compiled using such version , the version of delphi must remain without updates. but each time which i start the Delphi XE which not is updated i must cancel manually the updates  reported by the update checker. the question is how i Disable Delphi XE automatic update check?

Comment: Delphi 10.4 (sydney) is really stepping on my nerves. It dials home all the time. If I am not connected to internet, it opens the non-default browser and tries different URLs like http://updates.embarcadero.com/SWUpdate/scc http://delphiupdate.embarcadero.com/SWUpdate/scc http://cpevnxrdv.radstudioxe.com/SWUpdate/scc  http://radupdate.embarcadero.com/SWUpdate/scc  . Really disappointing Embarcadero... Really disappoint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can edit the registry. Under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0\AutoRun, rename the UpdateCheck key or remove the contents of UpdateCheck\ProgramToRun.

You need to do likewise under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, but don't forget about registry redirection on 64 bit - then the key is: Software\Wow6432Node\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0\AutoRun

Comment: Ken i follow your instructions, but when the ide starts the entry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0\AutoRun` is created again :(

Comment: Try getting rid of the one under HKLM too.

Comment: David, i check under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` but does not exist `Software\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0\AutoRun`

Comment: @Salvador, did you remove the contents of ProgramToRun? If I remove it, it doesn't get put back.

Comment: @Salvador, I just tested on my machine, and the contents of ProgramToRun is *not* added again on startup if I remove it.

Comment: @David, there isn't one under HKLM (in fact there are no XE-related entries under HKLM, at least on Win7 64; there isn't even a CodeGear, Embarcadero, or Borland entry there at all).

Comment: @Ken i'am using Win7 and 64 bit too, i tested deleting the the value of the `ProgramToRun`  and the value if filled again  when Delphi XE is started.

Comment: It's under `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node` – I thought everyone knew about that by now!

Comment: @David: Argh! I *did* know that; I just spaced for a minute. (I don't spend a lot of time in the registry in Win7; apparently not near enough. <g>) Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks @David, i search under `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node` and i rename the `AutoRun` key and now works ok.

Comment: @Ken you can update your answer with the comments to  mark as accepted or maybe @David can wrote a new answer?

Comment: @David, thanks for the edit. I was in the process of doing so (and giving you credit for the additional info) when SO alerted me someone else had edited while I was doing so. It was nice of you to edit my answer instead of adding your own. :)

Answer (score 5):

On XE2 you don't have to poke around the registry manually - just run C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\DisableIDEUpdateCheck.reg

Comment: This also exists in Delphi 2010

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have patience to poke around the registry so I just did a repair install of Delphi - every time the install process ends it gives you the option to autocheck for updates or not.

HTH
MNG

Comment: By far the easiest is to un-check the option when you first install.